# Error deploying ASP .NET Core 3.1 Razor website to AWS Elastic Beanstalk 64bit Amazon Linux 2

Tags: asp.net-core, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm really struggling with getting a simple site deployed. I have gotten various errors in the last few hours that I have worked through, and right now I have this error in the log and I have no clue what it even means. It says for details see eb-engine.log but I think that is the log I am looking at (elastic beanstalk > environments > my-environment > logs)

> 2021/05/07 19:41:10.466712 [ERROR] An error occurred during execution
> of command [app-deploy] - [FlipApplication]. Stop running the command.
> Error: Register application failed because the registration of proc
> web failed:  startProcess Failure: starting process "web" failed:
> Command /bin/sh -c systemctl start web.service failed with error exit
> status 1. Stderr:Job for web.service failed because the control
> process exited with error code. See "systemctl status web.service" and
> "journalctl -xe" for details.
>
> 2021/05/07 19:41:10.466726 [INFO] Executing cleanup logic 2021/05/07
> 19:41:10.466813 [INFO] CommandService Response:
> {"status":"FAILURE","api_version":"1.0","results":[{"status":"FAILURE","msg":"Engine
> execution has encountered an
> error.","returncode":1,"events":[{"msg":"Instance deployment found a
> self-contained .NET Core application in your source
> bundle.","timestamp":1620416468,"severity":"INFO"},{"msg":"Instance
> deployment failed. For details, see
> 'eb-engine.log'.","timestamp":1620416470,"severity":"ERROR"}]}]}